# pycharm ipython package not loading?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I am trying to work on a ipython notebook on pycharm but I am not being able to use the packages
[image]

As you can see it says `pd` is not defined in my case.
Any idea why it is saying that?
Not just that, when I try to use `sns` it says sns is not defined as well.

I went to `file->settings->projectInterpreter` Below is a screnshot with pandas package installed.

Pandas was already installed before i started writing any code. Seaborn was installed manually later.
[image]

Could anyone explain why I am getting this error in pycharm?
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Well, according to the screenshot, you tried importing `pandas` after attempting to use `pd.read_csv`

Comment: no `pandas` already exists..do u mean I have to put second screenshot on top?

Comment: The order in which you evaluate cells matters. If you try to evaluate a cell in which a module is used before you attempt to import it in another cell, then the Python interpreter won't be able to find the module, because you haven't imported it, yet.

Comment: haha thank you so much i realised i have to run first cell first then the other. I am new to this python and pycharm thing. Thank you very much that helped

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have to run the first cell first then the others.